# returns after recursive calls

Tags: python, recursion, depth-first-search

What is the difference between returning before the recursive call and returning after the recursive call

For example, if I have some code like the following

```
class TreeNode:
  def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
    self.val = val
    self.left = left
    self.right = right


class TreeDiameter:

  def __init__(self):
    self.treeDiameter = 0

  def find_diameter(self, root):
    self.calculate_height(root)
    return self.treeDiameter

  def calculate_height(self, currentNode):
    if currentNode is None:
      return 0

    leftTreeHeight = self.calculate_height(currentNode.left)
    rightTreeHeight = self.calculate_height(currentNode.right)

    if leftTreeHeight is not None and rightTreeHeight is not None:
      diameter = leftTreeHeight + rightTreeHeight + 1
      self.treeDiameter = max(self.treeDiameter, diameter)

    return max(leftTreeHeight, rightTreeHeight) + 1
```

There is a base case where we return `0` if the `currentNode is None`. But `leftTreeHeight` and `rightTreeHeight` are being assigned the recursive calls

After the assignments the code eventually returns the `max(leftTreeHeigth, rightTreeHeight) + 1`

This return is done after the recursive calls and I thought that at this point the program will end but after putting through a debugger I noticed that the program continues and jumps around my recursive function.

I'm not sure how to describe it but my thought was inside the recursive function I'd go down the left and right subtrees and each time adding 1 if a node is found. Get the max height of the left and the max height of the right plus 1 for it's root node and at the very end return that max left tree height and max right tree height plus 1 for the root

I figured that all this will be done before a recursive call. I thought that anything after the recursive call will just happen once. I know this is not not how it works but if I can explain where I am not sure of how this program works I can write the steps out

so once we are in our recursive function `calculate_height`

1. return 0 if current node is null
2. assign the recursive function to `leftTreeHeight`
3. we continue step 2 while we have a node
4. finally return 0 when we are past the leaf node
5. assign the recursive function to `rightTreeHeight`
6. we continue step 5 while we have a node
7. finally return 0 when we are past the leaf node
8. go past our recursive calls and to our if statement and to my knowledge `leftTreeHeight` and `rightTreeHeight` should both be 0
9. assign to diameter the left height + right height and + 1 for the root node making diameter 1
10. update our max tree diameter in this case it'd be 1
11. then return the max of the left tree and right tree height and add 1 to that max value. Being that `leftTreeHeight` and `rightTreeHeight` are both 0 this should return `1`.

after that last step I thought the function will end and I don't understand how the code continues to jump around inside our recursive function. Plus, I know if it were to return 1 as I mentioned it'd always be 1 then and the result will be wrong. I'm not asking if I am correct because I know I am wrong I just want clarification. It's hard for me to picture it.

Comment: It returns from this recursive call, and continues in the previous call.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I never explicitly return this recursive call in my recursive function. I know I return at the very end but when writing my recursive calls I am just assigning it to the left and right tree heights

Comment: Do you understand how recursion works? There are multiple executions of the function. When it makes a recursive calls, the current execution is suspended, the recursive call is performed. When that returns, the original execution continues.

Comment: Side note: `if leftTreeHeight is not None and rightTreeHeight is not None:` is not needed, as this condition is *always* true.

Comment: So the algorithm is visiting the left and right tree and if a node is `None` we `return 0` But because the recursive functions continues after the recursive calls we start to add 1 node each time with that `return max(leftTreeHeight, rightTreeHeight) + 1` from the bottom to the top. I thought that before doing the recursive calls we would have had to `return 0 if None else return 1` it just seems weird to me that it is after the recursive call

Comment: That base case is false on legal nodes in the tree. It only runs when the node doesn't exist and therefore has a height of 0. I think this post and your thought process would benefit greatly from working through the execution on various small sample inputs. What does the function execution do when called with `None` as the root? How about a tree with 1, 2, 3 and 4 nodes in different arrangements? It's easier to think and analyze concretely on actual runs than talking abstractly about what you think it does theoretically.

Comment: In short, if you return before recursive calls, the recursive calls never happen, whereas returning after recursive calls (in this case, and typically) uses the result of the recursion to compute the return value. What's my height? I don't know, let me ask my children for their height, then add 1 to whatever the tallest sub-result is.